# Wrong positioning of Google Maps infoWindow

Tags: google-maps, infowindow

I have a website at http://arquitectospelomundo.com which displays several markers, combined by the markerclusterer function, which display, when clicked, an infowindow with some info. When clicking directly on the map, the info window appears on the right spot; but when clicking on the sidebar (on one of the pictures), the info window goes out of bounds.
This was working correctly and suddenly changed; I am trying to figure it out but so far with no success. I would appreciate any help pointing me in the right direction.
Thank you.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself, not just a link to a problem website.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the disclaimer. I'll try to be more accurate next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems the issue is related to the MarkerClusterer.

When the marker where the click has been triggered is inside a cluster the map-property of the marker is null and you get the wrong position.

Possible solution:

When the marker is within a cluster use a hidden marker(hidden via `visible`) as anchor for the infoWindow:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   //create the dummy-marker on first click
   if(!map.get('dummy')){
     map.set('dummy',new google.maps.Marker({map:map,visible:false}))
   }
   var latLng = marker.getPosition();

   //when the marker is within a cluster
   if(!marker.getMap()){
    //set position of the dummy
    map.get('dummy').setPosition(latLng);
    //use dummy as infowindow-anchor
    marker= map.get('dummy');
   }
    map.panTo(latLng);
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map,marker);

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. I don't know why this happened, since it was working a few days ago! But this code solved the question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Marker clusterer and outside clicks to the map, opening infowindows. The solution by @Dr.Molle with dummy markers is a nice direction, but the problem is that you can use the dummy to pan to, but the listener triggers a click on the marker which is not on the map. The correct infowindow opens, but the autopan feature has no way of knowing where to pan to, so it stays where it was after the last click. This is a problem with repeated clicks from outside the map. The first click goes okay, but the second or third one goes wrong, depening on if it was in a cluster or not.

The solution I found tests if the marker is in a cluster, if yes, attaches it to the map, and removes it after the click (not sure if that is neccessary, maybe to prevent the map from getting slow). I put it in the function that is called with each click from outside. But maybe you can also build it into the event listener. This works perfectly for me:

```
function openInfoWindow(id){

    googlemap.setZoom(13);
    var marker = markers[id];
    var latLng = marker.getPosition();

    if(!marker.getMap()){ //if the clicked marker is in a cluster, so it is not attached to a map

        marker.setMap(googlemap); //attach it to the map
        google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click'); // the standard trigger, opens infowindow 
        googlemap.panTo(latLng); 
        marker.setMap(null); //detach it from the map (not sure if necessary

    } else {

        google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click'); 
        googlemap.panTo(latLng);

    }

    return false;
}
```